# "Relieved at" versus "relieved from"

Tags: prepositions

Take the following headlines I've found online:

> 1) Seniors **relieved at** temporary reprieve for community center.
>
> 2) Egypt **relieved at** decision to lift crowd ban in Ghana World Cup qualifier.

I would have said "relieved from" if I had written these.  Could anyone help me understand the difference between the prepositions "at" and "from" in this context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the construction "X is relieved from Y", *relieved* acts as a verb and signifies that the “burden” of Y is lifted off of X. The same thing is expressed with the preposition "of".

> The commanding officer was relieved from duty.
> An unexpected inheritance relieved William of his debts.

In the construction "X is relieved at Y", *relieved* acts as an adjective and signifies that X feels a ‘sense of relief’, a sense that a burden of anxiety has been lifted off of him, **because Y happened**. That is the case in your headlines:

> Seniors feel a sense of relief because the community center gained a 'reprieve' (*presumably the center was going to be closed, but the closure was temporarily cancelled*).
>
> Egypt feels less anxious because it has been decided that crowds will not be banned in the Ghana World Cup qualifier.

Comment: Thanks for the nice examples. It was good examples what I was lacking to express the answer lucidly.+1 for the nice and easy-to-understand post.

Comment: For completeness's sake, the use of the word in the sense "A robber relieved William of his wallet" is fairly common as well.  Perhaps this is a sort of sarcastic usage of Stoney's "relieved William of his debts."

Comment: @BobRodes That's exactly what it is. *Relieve* goes back to L *levis*, "light (weight)", and becomes "raise" in the senes of lifting or lightening a burden.

Comment: Yes, sarcastic because one doesn't typically consider one's wallet to be a burden, except perhaps in inverse proportion to the amount of money in it.  :)