# When to use 'at' or 'from' after an adjective

Tags: prepositions

Yesterday, I asked the difference between **at** and **from** following the adjective **relieved**.  I was met with a great [answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/10710/relieved-at-versus-relieved-from) describing the differences between the prepositions following that particular adjective.

I now know this example is grammatically correct:

> I was relieved **at** the news that my grandmother's surgery was successful.

However, I'm still confused as to what the differences between the two are after different adjectives.  Consider the following sentences (I don't know if these are correct or not -- I'm only basing them off what sounds the best to my ears):

> I became hungry **at** the smell of the cookies.
>
> I was exhausted **from** working all day.
>
> I got excited **at** the sight of her face.
>
> I'm broke **from** having spent all my money at the bar.

I know there are better ways to word these examples with altogether different prepositions, but I'm trying to understand these particular two.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's basically the same as your other question and its answer.

In all your examples here, ***at*** indicates an instantaneous **event** (not related to anything leading up to that event) had an effect; ***from*** indicates that the effect stemmed from an existing or long-standing **condition**.

> I became hungry **at** the smell of the cookies.
> *The smell of the cookies reached you and you became hungry (instantaneous).*
>
> I was exhausted **from** working all day.
> *Working all day is a long-standing condition, not instantaneous.*
>
> I got excited **at** the sight of her face.
> *You saw her face and in an instant became excited.*

The last one is more interesting:

> I'm broke **from** having spent all my money at the bar.

Although you could have spent all your money in one transaction, so that you instantaneously became penniless, the use of the **continuous** *having spent* means that the state of penury has continued since that time. Consequently you use ***from***.

You could even make a more ambiguous case with

> I'm broke from all the expenditure I incurred.

But the same analysis applies: you incurred all the expenditure, and an hour later you had still incurred all that expenditure. It's not the same as suddenly seeing someone or smelling cookies.

Answer (score -2):

a nit being picked .. your sentence "I got excited at the sight of her face." is not using "got" correctly .. you did not obtain anything in the past from seeing her face ..

a correct sentence could be "I became excited at ... "